# DDD modeling 1:1...N relationships with query performance in mind

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm a DDD beginner, and I have a legacy project which would surely benefit from a proper domain layer. The application has to be modified to support multiple application and UI layers. The domain logic is at the moment implemented using the transaction script pattern. Basically I inherited a DB structure which is not allowed to be altered, the new application should be a drop in replacement of the old one.

I stumbled upon an interesting modelling problem in a small part of the domain, which I'm sure experienced DDD practitioners will find interesting. I can't be too specific about the problem, so I'll describe a problem which closely matches mine.

## Problem description

Let's suppose we should manage a collection of products. Products are identified by ids, they contain some description, and every product has a few images associated with it. Here comes the tricky part. The images, their contents, are physically stored in the DB, so they are huge chunks of data. (let's just ignore now how good or bad is storing images in a DB, it's just an example). There are some invariants that must be enforced on adding/editing/removing products.

**Adding products**

- A product is only valid if it has images associated with it, without adding images a new product should not be allowed to be entered
- Every product must be associated with exactly 5 images, no more, no less.
- The order of images associated with the product must be maintained

**Editing products**

- Images of existing products can be replaced, but the number and order of the associated images should be maintained

**Removing products**

- When a product is removed, all of the images associated with it should also be removed

## Considered solutions

[The class diagrams of various solutions](http://i46.tinypic.com/2m2tb7o.png)

### Solution 1:

The simplest way to model these concepts would be the following.
The Product is the AR. The Images associated with the Product can be accessed and modified through the Product, so Product is responsible for enforcing the 5 Images rule. The advantage of this approach is that invalid Products can't be created or edited in a way to make them invalid, and no Images will be left behind when a Product is removed. So the aggregate if formed around the transaction boundary. The problems with this approach is that in the vast majority of cases the UI would just need to present the list of products, and maybe to modify their description. The UI would very rarely need to display or modify the Images associated with the product. So 95% of the cases huge amounts of unnecessary data would be loaded into the memory.

Lazy loading? The domain model should be implemented in a language which doesn't have ORM tools with lazy loading support. Implement my own lazy loading mechanism? The domain objects shouldn't be aware of the way they're persisted or if they're persisted at all. Instead Solution 2 is recommended by Vaughn Vernon.

### Solution 2:

The querying performance problems can be solved with this approach by favoring small aggregates and following the reference other aggregates by identity rule. Vaughn Vernon has a great [series of articles](http://domaindrivendesign.org/library/vernon_2011) describing how to achieve this.

The aggregate is split into two parts Product and ImageSet. Both of them are referencing ProductId as a value object. The Product would be responsible for enforcing the no product without Images rule, and the ImageSet would enforce the no ImageSet without 5 images rule. Querying is not a problem anymore, the ImageSet would be retrieved only when it's needed by a service.
However, this problem is a lot more complex then what Vernon describes in his articles (0...N association). The problem is that the creation of a Product would lead to modifying or creating 2 aggregates, which eliminates the purpose of modelling aggregates around transaction boundaries. The service which adds the new Product would be responsible for transaction management.

### Solution 3:

The final solution would be the use of bounded contexts. So for simplicity we name them BC1 and BC2. In BC1 a Product would just contain the ProductDetails. Services interested in querying Products for their details and maybe modifiyng them would use BC1 (ProductRepository in BC1 wouldn't allow adding or removing products, just querying/modifying existing ones). In BC2 a Product would contain the ProductDetails and the Images associated with it. So services interested in adding/removing products, and modifying/retrieving their images would use BC2. Commmon value objects and entities would be shared between these 2 BCs.

This solution would solve all the transactional consistency and querying performance problems. However, I'm not sure based on their definition BCs should be created in response to these kinds of problems.

I'm sorry for the long question, but I feel I should really point out which kinds of solutions I've already considered. And sorry for the linked images, I'm not allowed to upload images yet.

Answer (score 0):

An important observation in your use-case is that the problems of the 1st solution are isolated to the query side of the application. There is no reason to use the same model for processing commands and enforcing constraints as the model used for queries. The [read-model pattern](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) can be used to separate the reads from the writes which would allow you to create specific read-models for specific UI requirements and the read-model won't affect your domain model. While it is tempting to utilize the same model for reading as the one for writing, especially given that most ORMs support intricate queries and given the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), in practice it is much easier to separate the read model from the executable domain model.

Also, the series of articles by Vaughn Vernon are a great resource for understanding intricacies of aggregate design, however the central focus of the articles is on how to partition aggregates based on behavioral requirements not query requirements.